# input data and output table

Tags: database, search, table, input

I need a solution to do this with WP.

In admin: I need to input data into database (name, surname, certification, level, date of issue).

In Frontend: client can use a specific search field to search within the inserted data and get a table with the results. (name, surname, certification, level, date of issue).

Any module can do this please.

Comment: What is a module? What have you tried already? What research have you done?

Comment: I tried TablePress, it's good as a module, but it shows all the data in the table, I just need to show a search field in the frontend when the client does a search the table shows up according to the search criteria.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally done with installing "TablePress" and its extension "Inverted Filter" and making some code edits

please follow this for more details

https://tablepress.org/

https://wordpress.org/support/topic/how-to-not-show-the-result-of-the-search-query-until-enter-key-is-pressed